# Автоматизация сборки трех проектов на Maven и Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, автоматизация

**Дано:** три проекта. Первый проект - это Java EE проект (включающий три модуля) на системе Maven, второй и третий - это Android проекты на Gradle. Все это цельная система, которая поставляется множеству фирм.

**Задача:** сделать автоматическую сборку проекта в 5 вариациях, подменяя значения для каждой конкретной сборки. То есть каждая фирма имеет свои значения (ключи доступа к Google сервисам, домены, IP) и для сборки под конкретную фирму нужно включить ее ключи. Значения как в .java файлах, так и в .xml.

**Вариант решения:** хранить значения для каждой фирмы в отдельном файле (допустим, `values.txt`) в списке ключ=значение. В основном проекте делать вместо реальных значений заглушки типа `String accessKey = "$ACCESS_KEY$"`. При сборке копировать проект в отдельную папку фирмы, подставлять значения, собирать, забирать сгенерированные файлы и удалять обратно. Все это написать на bash или Java + bash.

---

**Вопрос:** как проще всего решить поставленную задачу?

Comment: проще прочитать про ресурсы и использовать стандартный https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, благодарю, это именно то, что нужно. Теперь хоть знаю, как это называется :). Добавьте, пожалуйста, в ответ. Буду заниматься этим только через пару дней и внесу в ответ дополнение о аналогичном функционале у Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Для Maven** вы можете использовать **Maven Resources Plugin**. Вам надо правильно настройить [Filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

```
<build>
  ...
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
    ...
  </resources>
  ...
</build>
```

Для Gradle вы можете тоже использовать [Filtering](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:filtering_files)

```
processResources {
   filter ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
      "ACCESS_KEY": project.property('access_key')
   ]
}
```